# What is meant by equivalent directions of space?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, symmetry, coordinate-systems

My Mechanics professor assigned me this question but I needed a bit of clarification on a given condition, the question is as follows:

Compute the Lagrangian for a free particle in an $(n+m)$-dimensional universe with the following property:

- $n$ directions of space are equivalent to each other and the remaining $m$ directions are equivalent to each other.  However, no direction of the first set is equivalent to any direction of the other set.

I was confused about what is meant by $n$ equivalent directions of space. Are they all collinear? And with the remaining $m$ equivalent directions, if this implies that they are collinear wouldn't this just be a 2-dimensional axis question?

Comment: To me, “equivalent” directions are Cartesian coordinates that can be interchanged without changing the equation of motion.

Comment: @G.Smith would this imply that a free particle in this universe will have $n+m$ 2nd order Eqns of motion from the Lagrangian?

Answer (score 0):

As a simple example, imagine rubbing your hand on some wood. Running your hand along the grain of the wood feels different from running your hand against the grain of the wood. Another example would be in your every day life: motion in the plane of the earth is quite different than perpendicular to it due to gravity! Thinking more mathematically, you could imagine that, for instance, there is a different potential in the  direction than the  direction. Or in 3 dimensions, a potential that depends only on 2+2 and ; indeed this is how you could implement gravity on Earth